# Finding the limit of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: calculus

how do I go about finding the limit of ${a_n}$?

Let $a_n$ be defined recursively by

$$a_1 =1$$

$$a_{n+1}=(1+2a_n)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Find an $a$ satisfying $a=(1+2a)^{1/2}$ and then try to prove tat this is the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use induction to show that the sequence is increasing and bounded above.

Note that $a_1 < 3$.  If $a_n < 3$ then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 + 2a_n} < \sqrt{7} < 3$.

Comment: Because $a_1 = 1 < 3$ and $a_n < 3 \implies 1 + 2a_n  < 7 \implies a_{n+1} < \sqrt{7} < 3.$

Comment: Assume the limit exists. If so the limit satisfies $L = \sqrt{1+2L} \implies L = 1 + \sqrt{2}$. So using any number greater than $L$ is a good choice to prove the sequence is bounded. Since you showed the sequence is increasing then if the limit exists it must be the least upper bound.